# What is the most efficient way to add Google Slides with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I currently have an array of slide ids that I am using to copy over slides from one Google Slide deck to another. Unfortunately this is a very slow operation and takes upwards of 3 minutes to run. Is there a more efficient way to insert slides?

```
for (var i = 0; i < slideIdArray.length; i++) {
    var nextID = slideIdArray[i]
    var nextSlide = slideDeck.getSlideById(nextID)
    sendDeck.insertSlide((i+1),nextSlide)
    }
```

Comment: How many slides are you copying? If you want to copy the same slides over and over, wouldn't it be better to duplicate the entire presentation and start the new one from there?

Comment: So it could range from 50-100 slides. The reason I need to use the code above is because the app script runs depending on a selection made by the user which determine which slides to copy over.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your way of doing it is the only optimal way, this takes a lot to run because of the amount of slides to copy.

You could also create a Feature Request on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918) to ask for a method on the [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) batch request for copying Slides.